# Remove try catch and handle the exception using exceptionhandler in rest api service using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, exceptionhandler

Want to handle the exception from only exceptionhandler class of API. Is there any way can remove all the try-catch of the API.

Using the @exceptionhandler but purpose not solved from this approach. Is there any way don't required try catch?

Comment: What is you have tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, all you need is a class with a `@ControllerAdvice` annotation on top of it, and to make it extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`
ex:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    // just for the example but you should probably handle specific exceptions rather than handle 'Exception.class'
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> processError(Exception exception) {
        // do something with the exception
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Oups", INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    ...
}
```

And of course you need to remove the `try-catch` or re-throw the exceptions otherwise they wont be catched by the `ControllerAdvice`.

see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.1.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html